# ¿Alguien sabe por que no se abre la imagen?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, imagen, diseño-de-clases, pillow

Tomé este código de la red, y solo cambié la imagen por una que tenía en computadora.
Luego cambié el código a hacerlo con una clase, pero cuando lo ejecuto abre la ventana, intenta abrir la imagen, pero no la abre ¿Alguien sabe por qué?
Este es el código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Digital_clock():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mywindow=tk.Tk()
        self.mywindow.geometry("1600x1300")
        self.mywindow.title("Creando un reloj Digital")
        self.mywindow.config(background='#1f2f3f')
        self.imagen_label=tk.Label(text="",font=('Tahoma',44),fg='#ffffff', bg='#77a922',pady=10, padx=10)
        self.imagen_label.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.update_image()
        self.mywindow.mainloop()



    def update_image(self):
        path = "DVR2.jpg"
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        self.imagen_label=tk.Label(image = img)
        

Digital_clock()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un problema muy recurrente cuando usas `PhotoImage`donde cuando tu sales de la función, se borra la imagen antes de que la puedas usar. Para poderla usar, debes asignar la imagen a tu objeto, de la siguiente manera:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Digital_clock():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mywindow=tk.Tk()
        self.mywindow.geometry("1600x1300")
        self.mywindow.title("Creando un reloj Digital")
        self.mywindow.config(background='#1f2f3f')
        self.imagen_label=tk.Label(text="",font=('Tahoma',44),fg='#ffffff', bg='#77a922',pady=10, padx=10)
        self.imagen_label.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.update_image()
        self.mywindow.mainloop()



    def update_image(self):
        path = "DVR2.jpg"
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        
        self.mywindow.img = img
        self.imagen_label=tk.Label(image = img).pack()
        

Digital_clock()
```

Además de eso no olvides agregar el `pack()` cuando estas instanciando la imagen.

Espero te haya servido. ¡Saludos!